# Verwendung von vertreiben -- Glauben vertreiben

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

Ich bezweifle die Verwendung von "vertreiben" in dem folgenden Satz.

> Gleichwohl hegt eine Minderheit weiterhin Zweifel an der Begründung
> der getroffenen Massnahmen, und auch die geschicklichsten politischen
> Aussagen können die beharrlichen Glauben nicht vertreiben.

Ist der Satz allgemein gesprochen richtig und sinnvoll, und insbesondere die Verwendung von vertreiben in diesem Zusammenhang.

Comment: Woher kommt der Satz?

Comment: Wo kommt das Zitat her - Schweizer Presse? Im Deutschen muss es "Maßnahmen" heißen, da ein langes A dem S vorangeht (siehe auch Fußball).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Der Satz ist zwar verständlich, ist aber misslungen.

1. Ein Adjektiv "geschicklich" gibt es nicht (und damit auch nicht den Superlativ "geschicklichst"). Das Wort kommt nur als Bestandteil von "Ge­schick­lich­keit" vor. Das korrekte Adjektiv ist "geschickt". Aber auch dieses passt nicht wirklich in den Satz.
2. Glaube wird nicht *vertrieben*, sondern *erschüttert*.

Mein Vorschlag:

> Gleichwohl hegt eine Minderheit weiterhin Zweifel an der Begründung der getroffenen Maßnahmen, und auch die überzeugendsten (politischen) Argumente können den festen Glauben nicht erschüttern.

Comment: Einen Wolf kann man vertreiben, dann ist er fort. Eine Wand kann man erschüttern, dann ist sie vielleicht beschädigt, aber sie steht noch. Wieso sollte man einen Glauben nicht vertreiben können?

Comment: `Eine Minderheit hegt gleichwohl Zweifel an der Begründung der getroffenen Massnahmen und auch die geschicksten politischen Aussagen können die beharrlichen Glauben nicht vertreiben.`  ?

Comment: Position of gleichwohl kilngt hier besser für mich

Comment: @kiriloff Beide Varianten sind korrekt. Ich vermute, dass der Satz als Abgrenzung zu etwas dient, das zuvor gesagt wurde. In diesem Fall würde ich stilistisch "Gleichwohl hegt eine Minderheit ..." bevorzugen.

Comment: @userunknown Man kann vieles vertreiben, aber die Kombination "Glauben vertreiben"  habe ich noch nie gehört oder gelesen. Das heißt zugegebenermaßen nicht viel, ich kann hier nicht für die Gesamtheit der Deutschsprechenden etwas behaupten. Es würde mich interessieren, ob Du das so gelesen hast oder es selbst so sagen würdest. Eine Suche per Google liefert jedenfalls nur einzigen Treffer auf Bibel-TV https://www.bibeltv.de/mediathek/videos/309544-angst-vertreibt-glauben. Und auch da nur im deutschen Titel des Videos.  Der amerikanische Originaltext ist "If my faith gives way to my fear."

Comment: Dagegen liefert eine Suche nach " Glauben erschüttern" massenweise Treffer.

Comment: man kann Glauben erschüttern oder austreiben. Vertreiben ist meist etwas physischens und weniger etwas metaphysisches oder geistiges - obwohl man ja böse Gedanken oder Geister vertreiben kann.

Comment: @kiriloff Das Wort "geschicksten" gibt es auch nicht.  Als Superlativ von "geschickt" wäre "geschicktesten" zu nehmen. Das Wort "geschickt" passt aber nicht als Attribut zu "Aussage".

Comment: @KritikerderElche: Ich führe nicht Buch über Formulierungen, die ich schon gehört oder gelesen habe. Für die Frage, ob die Formulierung sinnvoll ist, ist die bisherige Häufigkeit auch unerheblich. Die Häufigkeit von "Glauben erschüttert" steht nicht zur Disposition; es ist völlig gleichgültig, wie häufig etwas den Glauben erschüttert hat. Ein erschütterter Glaube kann fortbestehen und drückt daher etwas anderes als ein vertriebener Glaube aus, der offenbar nicht mehr fortbesteht. "Glaube gefunden"  könnte noch viel häufiger benutzt werden und passt trotzdem nicht.

Comment: @planetmaker: Und kann man Zeit vertreiben, oder Angst? Welche Bedeutung hat die Frage, was am häufigsten vertrieben wird, für die Beantwortung der Frage? Werden nicht am häufigsten Zeitschriften vertrieben oder Kosmetika, Tupperware oder Telefonverträge?

Comment: @userunknown Ich schlage vor, dass Du eine eigene Antwort schreibst und darin Stellung beziehst, ob Du "Glauben vertreiben" für eine passende Formulierung hältst. Dein erster Kommentar legt das nahe.

Comment: @KritikerderElche: Hast Du Widerwillen gegen Kritik und Zweifel? Wieso räumst Du nicht ein, dass Dein Argument schwach war, wenn Dir nichts einfällt, es zu stützen? Da es sonst keiner macht ist es wohl nötig, das Vertreiben des Glaubens zu verteidigen, da hast Du Recht.

Answer (score -1):

Glauben vertreiben kann man, wie man die Zeit vertreiben kann oder Zweifel, die schlechte Laune und vieles mehr. Gängig ist die Formulierung wohl nicht, aber die schlechten Alternativen, die in Kommentaren aufgeboten wurden, bedeuten etwas anderes, wie beispielsweise "erschüttern". Glaube ist, im Gegensatz zu Wölfen, die man buchstäblich vertreiben kann, etwas abstraktes, insofern ist "vertreiben" eine bildhafte Sprache, die im Deutschen keinem Regelwerk unterliegt, das Metaphern erlaubt oder verbietet.

Im Deutschen müsste es allerdings "Maßnahmen" mit scharfem S heißen, da das A davor lang ist, wie bei Fußball. Im Schweizer Deutsch gibt es allerdings kein scharfes S, und man würde tatsächlich ein Doppel-S schreiben.

"Die geschicklichsten politischen Aussagen" könnte eine Fusion von "geschicktesten" und "schicklichen" Aussagen sein, ist aber womöglich einfach nur ein Flüchtigkeitsfehler. Schicklich ist etwas, dass mit den guten Sitten konform geht - eine Absicht würde ich nicht vollkommen ausschließen wollen. Sollte es aber wirklich ein Schweizer Text sein, so könnte dort auch ein anderer Sprachgebrauch herrschen. Es kommt sporadisch vor, dass in Schweiz und Österreich Formulierungen Usus sind, die das hochdeutsche Ohr befremden.

Comment: Instruktionen missverständelig, spiele nun Fassball

Comment: wat mich hier eher an dem Satze stören tät wer der (scheinbare) Plural von Glauben

Comment: @vectory "können die beharrlichen Glauben nicht vertreiben" stört natürlich. Entweder "können den beharrlichen Glauben nicht vertreiben" oder "können die beharrlichen Überzeugungen  nicht vertreiben".

Comment: "Glauben" als Plural aufzufassen hat mich auch gestört, aber ohne weiteren Kontext ist nicht auszuschließen, dass es richtig ist - in dubio pro reo. Der eine glaubt an Buddha, der zweite an Jesus, der dritte an Mohammed: 3 Glauben. Die Mehrzahl war jedenfalls nicht Thema der der Frage, sondern das Vertreiben. Kann man die Glauben vertreiben, beispielsweise durch Rationalität?

Comment: es deutet aber halt auf eine Google Übersetzung oder sonst was hin. *Steht im Wörterbuch, jau, nehm ich!* So funktioniert das aber nicht